# jquery autocomplete on php doesnt work with id

Tags: php, jquery

my problem is to put an id to autocomplete with class work fine...

HTML CODE:

```
  <label>USUARIO:</label><input type='text' name='username' value='' class='auto' align='center'>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    //autocomplete
$('#username').autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 0
    });             

});
</script>
```

if i change `$('#username')` to `$('.auto')` works perfectly my head will blow

Comment: Your input tag does not have an ID attribute with the value `username`.

Comment: flagged as typo. All you have to do is add `id='username'` to your input tag and you should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that 'username' is actually the value of the 'name' attribute in your HTML code, not an 'id' attribute. jQuery expects this to be an 'id' attribute for $('#username') to work.